# WebSocketClient in C

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm currently trying to make an Android application that receives data through a WebSocket (mp3 data), and plays it through OpenSl Es (native audio library). To do that I need to have a WebSocket in my C code. It's quite easy to have one in the java side but I just can't find a C library that implements websocket. Which library should I go for ? And should I add the said library in my Android.mk file etc ? Or could I just put the file in my folder and use it from other C file ?

Comment: use exoplayer - you already got WSDataSource, didnt you? why didn't you use it?

Comment: @pskink I couldn't figure it out. also I need to go native now

Comment: native? meaning jni? why?

Comment: @pskink yes jni. To use Open Sl ES that has less latency

Comment: ok so i played mp3 using exoplayer and it works just fine, btw it uses `MediaCodec` / `MediaExtractor` that are implemented natively

Comment: @pskink I'll try again then, guess I did something wrong last time

Answer (score 1):

It's too late to help the OP but for the benefit of others having a similar problem. Here is an easy to integrate WebSocket client for C++. Should be easy to add your own c wrapper if needed. Search easywsclient on github. Works well on Windows and Android.
https://github.com/dhbaird/easywsclient